# on change jquery only works once for db values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have 3 select boxes with the ids first-choice, second-choice and third choice.

```
  <select id="first-choice" style="border-radius: 0; width: 100%;"  class="form-control" name="area">
                                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                                    <option value="">All</option>
                                    <?php
                                    global $connection;
                                    $area_query = "SELECT DISTINCT area FROM archivo WHERE LENGTH(area) > 1";
                                    $result_area = mysqli_query($connection, $area_query );
                                    while($row_a = mysqli_fetch_array($result_area)):
                                    ?>
                                        <option><?php echo $row_a['area'] ?></option>
                                    <?php endwhile;?>
                                </select>

<select id="second-choice" style="border-radius: 0; width: 100%"  class="form-control" name="category">
                                   <option value="">-Select-</option>

                                </select>

<select id="third-choice" style="border-radius: 0; width: 100%"  class="form-control" name="product">
                                    <option value="">-Select-</option>


                                </select>
```

And i have the following jquery code:

```
$(document.body).on('change','#first-choice',function(){
    //alert('Change Happened');
    $("#second-choice").load("../config/select_eng.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());

});

 $(document.body).on('change','#second-choice',function(){
    //alert('Change Happened');
    $("#third-choice").load("../config/select_eng_2.php?choice=" + $("#second-choice").val());

});
```

The thing is that it only works once, from the first select box to the second but not from the second to the third. Why is this? please help.

the php code for the first one:

```
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM archivo WHERE area='$choice' AND base = 'Engineering'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option >" . $row{'category'} . "</option>";
```

the php code for the second:

```
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT platform_type FROM archivo WHERE category='$choice'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='{$row['platform_type']}'>" .  $row{'platform_type'} . "</option>";
```

}

Comment: why you have 2 id on each select?

Comment: hi i removed the id="area" on all of them but it still doesnt work

Comment: Please share you result from server which you are trying to load into select element. Note that .load() loads result into matching elements.

Comment: i updated to show the php code, the thing is if i echo out something that doesnt come from the db it works just not with rows from the db, i checked my querys and they are correct.

Comment: I have added a snippet please try that. On second select there is no value for option to be sent to server to load third select. Try with that.

Comment: "if i echo out something that doesnt come from the db it works just not with rows from the db"  it only indicates that either you are not getting any result from database otherwise as per your comment it works. Provide your database tables.

Comment: See the code `$row{'platform_type'}` must be `$row['platform_type']` and `$row{'category'}`  must be `$row['category']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the exact copy of the second in select_eng.php.

```
     <select id="second-choice" style="border-radius: 0; width: 100%"  
     class="form-control" name="category" id="area">
           <option value="">-Select-</option>
           //Select option populated from the db
      </select>
```

and you can put the second select around span with id:

```
   //use this code in the main page.
  <span id="third-choice">
    <select id="second-choice" style="border-radius: 0; width: 100%"  
      class="form-control" name="category">
         <option value="">-Select-</option>
     </select>
 </span>

 //in select_eng.php, use this               

   $choice = $_GET['choice'];
   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT platform_type FROM archivo 
             WHERE category='$choice'";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   echo '<select id="second-choice" style="border-radius: 0; width: 100%"  
      class="form-control" name="category">';
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['platform_type'].'">'.$row['platform_type'] .'</option>';
   }
    echo '</select>';
```

id selector must be unique. You have two id`s in your select.  You do not need`id="area"` at all. Hope this may help.

Comment: i removed the id="area" but it still doesnt work, it works on  first-choice  to secont-choice but not from second-choice to third-choice

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again. As I used `<span id="third-choice"` for the second select, for the third select, you can use other name like `<select id="last-select">`

Comment: already did that and still doesnt work i updated the post with the php code the thing is if i echo out something that doesnt come from the db it works just not with rows from the db, i checked my querys and they are correct

Comment: use the code in my updated the answer. You say you checked your query and it works fine. If it works without database it is certain that it works with the DB as well if your db connection and query are fine.